# Laravel 6 upload file

Tags: laravel, forms, file, uploading

I have a big struggle about adding file uploading to an existing laravel 6 form.
I want to add the file url to database for future to be displayed (or downloaded).

When i try to do something nothing is happaning, nothing in DB nothing in file dir.

Here is my model:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'age',
    'last_rab',
    'names',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'last_pos',
    'cv',
    'msg',
    'status'
];
```

Here is my Controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'names' => 'required',
        'age' => 'required',
        'last_rab' => 'required',
        'last_pos' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'cv'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt|max:2048',
        'msg' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->captcha != 58) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('warning', 'Wrong');
    }

    $karieri = new Karieri;
    $karieri->age = $request->age;
    $karieri->last_rab =  $request->last_rab;
    $karieri->names = $request->names;
    $karieri->email = $request->email;
    $karieri->phone = $request->phone;
    $karieri->last_pos = $request->last_pos;
        
    if ($request->hasfile('cv')) {
        $file = $request->file('cv');
        $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
        $file->move(public_path() . '/storage/app/public', $name);
        $data = $name;
        $karieri->cv = json_encode($data);
    }

    $karieri->msg = $request->msg;
    $karieri->status = 0;
    $karieri->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Thanks');
}
```

Can somebody say how to do this?

Comment: Have you made sure the form you're using to submit the data has the correct `enctype`? In order to submit files through forms, they need to be `multipart/form-data`. `<form method="..." action "..." enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Also you should add the `file` rule to your `cv` field.

Comment: @IGP .... Just nothing to say. Absolutely forgot to put that in form section.... But what about if I have 2 field (one for text document other for img)?

Comment: Then you just make 2 inputs and validate them separately. `<input type="file" name="cv"> <input type="file" name="image">` `'cv' => 'required|file|...', 'image' => 'required|file|image'` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-image

Comment: @IGP Yep i Do this but what about controller:
`$files =[];
        if ($request->file('cv')) $files[] = $request->file('cv');
        if ($request->file('photo')) $files[] = $request->file('photo');
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
            $file->move(public_path() . '/storage/app/public', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
            $karieri->cv=$data[0];
            $karieri->photo=$data[1];
            }`

Comment: Don't use a foreach. That's overcomplicating things. `if ($request->hasFile('cv')) {  // handle cv } if ($request->hasFile('image') { // handle image }` .